# avoid long connection time

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a class called messaging. When an instance of the class is created a connection is made to a service which in turn has access to a database. This connection takes 5 seconds (`Messaging.Connection MESConnection = new Messaging.Connection();` below).The class has a method that the user can submit a message which puts some data in the database.

When a user presses a button i want to submit X number of messages to the database using threading. I have this working using the task parralel library but the issue is that the X threads create X instances of the class which means that the whole operation takes about 10 seconds if X is 30 for example.

How could i offline have say 10 connections open such that when messages are submitted, the connection to the database is already open and hence i could avoid the 5 second connection time?

**C# Code**

```
// Loop through and multithread


foreach (string container in containers)
        {

            int output = Convert.ToInt32(container);
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                Messaging.Connection MESConnection = new Messaging.Connection(); //Takes 5 seconds
                BSCContainerWorkflowResponse.BscContainerWorkflowResponse WorkflowResponse2;

                // Get device next step
                MESConnection.xmlMessage = Messaging.BscContainerNextTaskRequest(Convert.ToString(output));

                // Send message to MES
                String result;

                result = MESConnection.SendMessage();
                if (result != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending message to MES: " + result);
                    return null;
                }

                result = MESConnection.GetReply();
                if (result != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error receiving message from MES: " + result);
                    return null;
                }


                WorkflowResponse2 = BSCContainerWorkflowResponse.ReadBscContainerWorkflowResponse(MESConnection.xmlReply);


                if (WorkflowResponse2.mes_message.msg_header.msg_stat < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error with mes Response " + " message stat:" + Convert.ToString(WorkflowResponse.mes_message.msg_header.msg_stat) + " Error source " + (WorkflowResponse.mes_message.msg_error.error_source) + " Error code " + (WorkflowResponse.mes_message.msg_error.error_code) + " Error string " + Convert.ToString(WorkflowResponse.mes_message.msg_error.error_string), "MES Message Error");
                    return null;
                }

                return WorkflowResponse2;

            }).ContinueWith(o =>
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.Name + " " + o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.Product.Name + " " + o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.Product.BscModelNumber + " " + o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.BscSerialNumber + " " + o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.TaskList.Name + " " + o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.TaskList.Revision + " " + Convert.ToString(o.Result.mes_message.msg_body.Container.MfgOrder.BscSWR));
                buttonSendBSCNextTaskRequestThreaded.Text = "Process";
                buttonSendBSCNextTaskRequestThreaded.Enabled = true;

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach would be to use a [connection pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710384/Creating-a-custom-database-connection-pool) to alleviate the long connection times. The ADO.NET providers have this built in. If your connection class doesn't, you can [implement one yourself](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710384/Creating-a-custom-database-connection-pool) as it could improve the performance of the entire application.

Although, the right approach in this particular situation would be to compare what takes longer:

- To create multiple connections to push the data through *or*
- Reuse a single connection to push the data through

This will depend on how much data you are pushing through and the *latency* involved.

To keep things simple, I'd probably start off with reusing 1 connection, and if found insufficient, try connection pooling. I'd only resort to parallelization if the latency is very high.

Always dispose of disposables if you are not using it anymore - a connection typically requires disposing.

Comment: It's simpler and more robust and scaleable to *not* use a single connection, rather open and close a connection immediately after working with the database. An open connection is one that keeps transactions and locks open, not to mention that it can only execute one command at a time. It's very easy to end up blocking multiple threads that all wait for an existing command to finish